# SQL Query help - using max() twice on same column

Tags: sql

I tried searching around for this, but honestly I'm not really sure exactly what to search on...so be patient if this has been asked before.

I have a table that has a list of events like this:

```
Date      Event 
-----     ------
1/1/2012  Event1
1/2/2012  Event1
1/4/2012  Event2
1/6/2012  Event1
etc.
```

What I am trying to do is do a select on this table, returning both the most recent date that `Event1` occured and the most recent date that `Event2` occured.  So using the above table as an example, I'd wish to see the following results:

```
Event 1      Event2
-------      ------
1/6/2012     1/4/2012
```

Any ideas on how to acheive this?  I know how to get these values individually

```
SELECT max(date) FROM table WHERE Event LIKE 'Event1'
```

just not together as one result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement with the `MAX()` function.

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'Event1' THEN date END) Event1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'Event2' THEN date END) Event2
FROM yourTable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce135/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query for any value on `event` column:

```
select MAX(date), event
from events_table
group by event;
```